# How to find certain files and copy them in a folder?

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp

I have a folder (name250) which contains several sub-directories.
I want my script to find certain files (tE1_sys_250.txt to tE99_sys_250.txt) in all the sub-directories and copy them in another folder (name250_sys).

This is my script but when I run it nothing happens.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/name250/
mkdir ../name250_sys
for a in {10..99}
do
`find . -name tE$a'_sys'_250.txt -exec cp {} ./name250_sys/ \;`
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the backquotes? They look very suspicious!

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
cd /name250/
```

That would attempt to change the directory to a "name250" directory contained in the root folder. I imagine you want:

```
cd ../name250_sys
```

Comment: no. my main folder is ~/name250/ and I wanted to make another folder (name250_sys) and copy the files inside the name250/ to that folder.

Comment: Ok, but in your original code you had /code250/, not ~/code250, so that's why it caught my eye. I see it's fixed in your answer, and you found the real problem as well, so good going, it's always more satisfying to DIY.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. my problem was the last part of the script which I had to add a line " cd .." before find command. Then, it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/name250/
mkdir ../name250_sys
cd ..
for a in {10..99}
do
`find . -name tE$a'_sys'_250.txt -exec cp {} ./name250_sys/ \;`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if following one line will help:

**if you are looking for 1-99**

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex '.*tE[0-9]{1,2}_sys_250\.txt' -exec cp {} ./name250_sys/ \;
```

**and if you are looking for 10-99**

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex '.*tE[0-9]{2}_sys_250\.txt' -exec cp {} ./name250_sys/ \;
```

Assuming you are only looking to copy such files